# Can I build image on Windows and run container on Linux?

Tags: spring, docker

I use intellij idea to develop spring boot application on my Win10 laptop, my production environment is centos 7, after I test on Windows successfully, want to build a docker image on Windows, and push to remote Docker Registry, and then login the centos 7, pull the image and running a container.

Is this a correct docker related development practice? or must install centos on virtualbox on my win10?

Answer (score 3):

No that's one of the beauties of Docker, you can develop anywhere.
The only issues you might face are permission problems, cause those are different between Windows and Linux. Just make sure to manually set all permissions correctly in your build and you should be fine.

Comment: @JamesHao make sure that you read the docs on docker.com. They have a good documentation. For the rest it's pretty much googling. Due to the variety of use cases docker can be used for, there isn't really "onle way to go".